# Delta function in Green's function

Tags: condensed-matter, greens-functions

I am working through Altland Simons 2nd edition. On page 225 we find:

> $$G_p = [1 - G_{0, p} \; \Sigma_p]^{\, -1} \,  G_{0, p} = [G_{0, p}^{\, -1} - \Sigma_{p}]^{-1}$$
> Finally, using the fact that $[G_{0, p}^{-1}\, ]^{ab} \; = (p^2 + r) \, \delta^{ab} $, we arrive at the formal solution
> $$G_p^{ab} = \left[(p^2 + r - \Sigma_p)^{-1} \, \right]^{ab} $$

My question: is $\delta^{ab}$ is the Kronecker delta function? If so, should it be $$G_p^{ab} = \left[((p^2 + r) \, \delta^{ab} - \Sigma_p)^{-1} \, \right]^{ab} $$ instead?

In case it helps, the $\delta^{ab}\; $ comes up earlier in the text (page 223):

$$G_0 \equiv \langle \phi^a (x) \phi^b(y) \rangle_0 \propto \delta^{ab}$$

For reference, the action is given in equation (5.37)

$$ S[\phi] \equiv \int d^d x \left( \, \frac{1}{2} \partial \phi \cdot \partial \phi + \frac{r}{2} \phi \cdot \phi + \frac{g}{4N} (\phi \cdot \phi)^2 \right), $$

where $\phi$ is the N-component vector field $\phi = \{\phi^a\}, a = 1, \ldots, N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like $\delta^{ab}$ is effectively the Kronecker delta. Your expression of $G^{ab}_p$ cannot be correct because it is of the form $[(A\delta^{ab}+B)^{-1}]^{ab}$. In fact the expression given for $G^{ab}_p$ is just $((p^2+r)\delta^{ab}-\Sigma_p \delta^{ab})^{-1}$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! Just to clarify, it's a typo and there should be a $\delta^{ab}$ in $\left[(p^2 + r - \Sigma_p)^{-1} \, \right]^{ab}$ as in your expression, or are you saying that there's a convention that anytime I see an expression like $\left[(p^2 + r - \Sigma_p)^{-1} \, \right]^{ab}$ it always means there is an implied $\delta^{ab}$ as in your expression?

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast If we really have $(p^2+r)\delta^{ab}$ in first instance, then yes, an expression like $[(p^2+r-\Sigma_p)^{-1}]^{ab}$ means that there is an implied $\delta^{ab}$ in front of $\Sigma_p$. But, in general, an expression of the form $[A+B]^{ab}$ just means that $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of the same type.